# Force turtle (netlogo) to maintain current heading (from point of hatching) rather than following heading and direction of its parent

Tags: netlogo

I am a beginner in Netlogo and trying to setup an agent (criminal) to shoot another agent (victim) when in range. One of the problems I am facing is how to keep the bullets - when ‘hatched’ from the criminal – to keep moving in a straight line. In other words, how can I make a turtle maintain its current heading?

Below is what I have unsuccessfully tried.

```
Hatch-bullets 1 [ set size 0.1
                  set color white
                  set label ""
                  set benergy 10
                  fd 1
                  set current-heading heading  
                 ]
      ask bullets [ ifelse any? humans-here with [pcolor = green]
          [ hit-target die ]
          [ set heading current-heading 
            fd 1
            set benergy benergy - 0.5 
            set heading current-heading
            ask humans-here [die]
            if benergy = 0 [die]
           ]
```

I was hoping bullet-heading (variable) will store the current heading at the poing of hatching, so that it can be used later for the life duration of the bullet as it travels in a straight line (which unfortunately does not on both counts)

The other related problem is that, one bullet will be hatched per tick (or every second tick) and each bullet needs to keep track of its own heading. Bullets should be moving on a straight line rather than following the movement of the parent.

I have seen the projectile game, but the code is not helpful

Comment: You don't have to do anything for a turtle to maintain its current heading. Its heading will only change if you change it.

Comment: Reading about hatch – it says that the hatched agent inherits the characteristics of its ‘parent’ so in this case – the criminal – which is set to constantly moving and seeking for a new target. Bullets have a similar behaviour – ie moving in different directions seeking for a new target, rather than moving in straight line from the point they got hatched. I want to give bullets their own properties including the heading hence the attempted code above. Each hatched bullet should keep moving in a straight line. I can’t seem to get them moving in a straight line from the point they have hatched

Comment: Sounds like the problem isn't at the time the bullet is created, but afterwards. But you've only shown the creation code, not the code for afterwards.

Comment: Thank you. I will add it in the original question above

Comment: Why do `set heading current-heading`? Why ever `set heading` at all after the bullet is initially created? The bullet's heading will only ever change if you change it, so you need to find the code that changes it, and stop doing that. Perhaps `set heading current-heading` is the offending line.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, something is changing the direction. However, It is with this line that the bullet remains straight for most of its journey - it's the closest I have been to making them go straight. Without that line the bullet has the same trajectory as the turtle that hatched it - in this scenario the criminal - and therefore one single bullet will move in different direction rather than in straight line. The idea was to store the original heading of the bullet so that it can be used again as a 'reminder' for the bullet.

Comment: Okay. I think that the problem is somewhere other than in the code you have shown us.

Comment: Many thanks. Interesting point. Even more intrigued as to what could be causing this. Others procedures that are related to the criminal are, hunt (looking for victim), sellectother (allows the possibility for the criminal to lose focus and head towards another human) – which is using either of the two procedures ( sellectkillnear or selectkilloneofnear) and shoot once target has been selected (shoot the procedure responsible for hatching the bullets)